# Up arrow in scheme interpreter sends ^[[A instead of history back

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I'm running mit-scheme-x86-64 and reading SICP.

For some reason the up and down arrows don't behave like they do in terminal/in every other interpreter.

They send ^[[A and ^[[B respectively.

I tried doing this in my .bashrc and it didn't work.

```
bind '"^[[A":history-search-backward'
bind '"^[[B":history-search-forward'
```

I'm actually not quite sure what I'm suppose to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) for these purposes:

> rlwrap runs the specified command, intercepting user input in order to
>   provide readline’s line editing, persistent history and completion.
>
> rlwrap tries to be completely transparent − you (or your shell)
>   shouldn’t notice any difference between command and rlwrap command −
>   except the added readline functionality, of course. This should even
>   hold true when you are re−directing, piping and sending signals from
>   and to command, or when command manipulates its terminal settings.
>
> There are many options to add (programmable) completion, handle
>   multi−line input, colour and re−write prompts. If you don’t need them
>   (and you probably don’t), you can skip the rest of this manpage.